# Configure proxy for certain port on Linux

Tags: linux, proxy, centos

The question might not what you thought it was by the title.
I have Linux machine running a Centos distribution. I have a certain script which sends HTTP requests but can not be configured to use proxies due to certain reasons.
What I'm looking for, is to configure a proxy connection only for the HTTP requests (port 80) while other connections such as SSH will work with the Server IP.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable :

```
http_proxy="http://PROXY:proxyport"   yourcommand
```

or export this and do what you need :

```
export http_proxy="http://PROXY_IP:proxyport"
yum update
```

Comment: It's good for commands ran from the command line but not for running scripts.